# How can I change the CSS of Devel::Cover in Perl?

Tags: perl, devel-cover

When running `./Build testcover` to test the code coverage, is there a way I can pass in some kind of option for using my own stylesheet, maybe as an override?

I have looked at the [Devel::Cover](http://search.cpan.org/~pjcj/Devel-Cover-1.08/lib/Devel/Cover.pm) CPAN documentation to no avail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the source of [Devel::Cover::Report::Html_minimal](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/PJCJ/Devel-Cover-1.08/lib/Devel/Cover/Report/Html_minimal.pm), it seems you would need to make your own report format by subclassing that and overriding `print_stylesheet()` to do what you want. That's the "easy" part...

Next you would need to get `Module::Build` to use your custom report format when running `cover`. Again, looking at the source, the default `testcover` action in `Module::Build` simply runs `$self->do_system('cover')` and as the `cover` script doesn't allow you to override the report format using an environment variable, you would have to override `ACTION_testcover()` in the build class for the given module.

It seems like just mangling the default CSS file after running `./Build testcover` as suggested in another answer is a much easier solution.

Comment: Marking this as the correct answer since I went with subclassing and overriding.

Answer (score 5):

The CSS file is `cover_db/cover.css`. Change at will.

Comment: Yes, I have already thought of that, but it seems tacky to have to change the generated css file. It would be nice if `Devel::Cover` could accept an additional override stylesheet.

Comment: You could always copy the HTML files to a directory with the corrected CSS file.